# how to print CSV from the third field

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, sed, csv

I want to capture the csv lines from the third field until and without the double quote (")

```
more test

"linux02","PLD26","net2-thrift-netconf","net.driver.memory","2"
"linux02","PLD26","net2-thrift-netconf","net.executor.cores","2"
"linux02","PLD26","net2-thrift-netconf","net.executor.instances","2"
"linux02","PLD26","net2-thrift-netconf","net.executor.memory","2"
"linux02","PLD26","net2-thrift-netconf","net.sql.shuffle.partitions","141"
"linux02","PLD26","net2-thrift-netconf","net.dynamicAllocation.enabled","true"
"linux02","PLD26","net2-thrift-netconf","net.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors","2"
"linux02","PLD26","net2-thrift-netconf","net.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors","2"
"linux02","PLD26","net2-thrift-netconf","net.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors","20"
```

I tried this

```
sed s'/,/ /g' test | awk '{print $3","$4","$5}' | sed s'/"//g'
,,
net2-thrift-netconf,net.driver.memory
net2-thrift-netconf,net.executor.cores
net2-thrift-netconf,net.executor.instances
net2-thrift-netconf,net.executor.memory
net2-thrift-netconf,net.sql.shuffle.partitions
net2-thrift-netconf,net.dynamicAllocation.enabled
net2-thrift-netconf,net.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors
net2-thrift-netconf,net.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors
net2-thrift-netconf,net.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors
,,
```

but I have a problem with my syntax because this syntax also prints ",," 
and the second syntax isn't elegant.

expected output:

```
net2-thrift-netconf,net.driver.memory,2
net2-thrift-netconf,net.executor.cores,2
net2-thrift-netconf,net.executor.instances,2
net2-thrift-netconf,net.executor.memory,2
net2-thrift-netconf,net.sql.shuffle.partitions,141
net2-thrift-netconf,net.dynamicAllocation.enabled,true
net2-thrift-netconf,net.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors,2
net2-thrift-netconf,net.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors,2
net2-thrift-netconf,net.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors,20
```

Comment: see please my update

Comment: Consider also, you can use `python` (included in just about every distro) and import the `csv` library for an easy time working with CSVs. https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Comment: Can the values in your fields possibly contain any commas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `sed` only:

```
sed -E 's/"//g; s/^([^,]*,){2}//' infile
```

- `s/"//g`, strips all double quotes.
- `^([^,]*,){2}`, start from begging of the line, strips everything followed by a comma and repeat this to maximum two times.

Or with `awk`:

```
awk -F\" '{$1=$2=$3=$4=$5=""}1' OFS="" infile
```

Answer (score 7):

It looks like it is just a matter or removing the quotes and then printing from the 3rd field until the end of the line:

```
$ tr -d \" < file | cut -d, -f3-
net2-thrift-netconf,net.driver.memory,2
net2-thrift-netconf,net.executor.cores,2
net2-thrift-netconf,net.executor.instances,2
net2-thrift-netconf,net.executor.memory,2
net2-thrift-netconf,net.sql.shuffle.partitions,141
net2-thrift-netconf,net.dynamicAllocation.enabled,true
net2-thrift-netconf,net.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors,2
net2-thrift-netconf,net.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors,2
net2-thrift-netconf,net.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors,20
```

So `tr -d \"` removes the quotes and `cut -d, -f3-` prints from the 3rd to the last `,`-separated fields.

Comment: can you change it in case we want to set your syntax after pipe line  as cat file |    tr ................

Comment: @yael feel free to use the code as you wish. As is now, I think the answer is more complete and easy to reproduce to others.

Answer (score 2):

You should really use a proper CSV parser for CSV data. Here's a way using ruby

```
ruby -rcsv -e '
  CSV.foreach(ARGV.shift) do |row|
    wanted = row.drop(2)   # ignore first 2 fields
    puts CSV.generate_line(wanted, :force_quotes=>false)
  end
' test
```

```
net2-thrift-netconf,net.driver.memory,2
net2-thrift-netconf,net.executor.cores,2
net2-thrift-netconf,net.executor.instances,2
net2-thrift-netconf,net.executor.memory,2
net2-thrift-netconf,net.sql.shuffle.partitions,141
net2-thrift-netconf,net.dynamicAllocation.enabled,true
net2-thrift-netconf,net.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors,2
net2-thrift-netconf,net.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors,2
net2-thrift-netconf,net.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors,20
```

or as a one-liner

```
ruby -rcsv -e 'CSV.foreach(ARGV.shift) {|r| puts CSV.generate_line(r.drop(2), :force_quotes=>false)}' test
```